# Security behaviour in Adobe Air

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am trying to load external SWFs in my Adobe AIR App. The loaded SWF is trying to access an URL to retrieve some informations via XML.
When starting the SWF by itself it works fine. When loading the SWF from the File.applicationStorageDirectory i will get an Security-Error because the loaded App is executed in a local-with-filesystem Sandbox appareantly. 
**First Question**: Is there a way to change this? That the loaded SWF is running in a network Sandbox?

Since that first attempt didn't worked i've moved the SWF to the app:// directory.
Now i'll get a Security-Error because there is no policy file on the Server available where the XML data should be retrieved.
**Second Question**: Why is the policy file not necessary when running the SWF by itself, but is necessary when trying to load the data from the application Sandbox? What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.

I am doing an ActionScript-based app btw. My goal here is the create an AIR Application that loads different modules on demand from a given internet ressource. The two applications are using the child/parentSandboxBridge to communicate.

I was using the SWFLoader class but did not correctly pass the LoaderContext with allowLoadBytesCodeExecution (or allowCodeImport for AIR2.0). As i was passing a LoaderContext with the mentioned variable, i was getting an VerifyError: Error #1053: Illegal override of activate in mx.managers.SystemManagerProxy since the AIR Application is done with Flex 4.0 and the loaded SWF is compiled with Flex 3.5.

The reason that error was thrown although the loadForCompatibility property was set to true was, that the SWFLoader class does not set the necessary applicationDomain for compatibility when a LoaderContext Object is passed. So i did the applicationDomain setting myself and everything works like a charm.
If anyone is interested in this procedure, just look into the SWFLoader::loadContent Method. In Flex 4 the interesting part starts at line 1836.